# Dot product and Cross product question

Tags: vector-analysis, cross-product

Let $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R^3$ be a three-times differentiable vector-valued function.

Is this statement true?

$f '(u) \cdot [ f '(u)  \times  f ''(u)] = 0$

If so how can it be justified or explained? Is it correct to say that these vectors are perpendicular?

Answer (score 0):

$f'(u)\times f''(u)$ is perpendicular to $f'(u)$ (the cross product of vectors is perpendicular to them),

and the dot product of perpendicular vectors is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. How do we know that f ' (u) and f ' (u) x f '' (u) are perpendicular to each other?

Comment: Because $a$ and $b$ are perpendicular to $a\times b$

Comment: Thank you very much.